# Combining Directory of Text Files into CSV, One File Per Line

Tags: bash

I have a large directory of text files, each rather complicated:

Say file1.txt:

> Am no an listening depending up believing. Enough around remove to
>   barton agreed regret in or it. Advantage mr estimable be commanded
>   provision. Year well shot deny shew come now had. Shall downs stand
>   marry taken his for out. Do related mr account brandon an up. Wrong
>   for never ready ham these witty him. Our compass see age uncivil
>   matters weather forbade her minutes. Ready how but truth son new
>   under.
>
> Am increasing at contrasted in favourable he considered astonished. As
>   if made held in an shot. By it enough to valley desire do. Mrs chief
>   great maids these which are ham match she. Abode to tried do thing
>   maids. Doubtful disposed returned rejoiced to dashwood is so up.

And file2.txt:

> Among going manor who did. Do ye is celebrated it sympathize
>   considered. May ecstatic did surprise elegance the ignorant age. Own
>   her miss cold last. It so numerous if he outlived disposal. How but
>   sons mrs lady when. Her especially are unpleasant out alteration
>   continuing unreserved resolution. Hence hopes noisy may china fully
>   and. Am it regard stairs branch thirty length afford.
>
> Blind would equal while oh mr do style. Lain led and fact none. One
>   preferred sportsmen resolving the happiness continued. High at of in
>   loud rich true. Oh conveying do immediate acuteness in he. Equally
>   welcome her set nothing has gravity whether parties. Fertile suppose
>   shyness mr up pointed in staying on respect.

What I need to do is to create a new file, say allfiles.txt that is:

```
Am no an listening depending up believing. Enough around remove to barton agreed regret in or it. Advantage mr estimable be commanded provision. Year well shot deny shew come now had. Shall downs stand marry taken his for out. Do related mr account brandon an up. Wrong for never ready ham these witty him. Our compass see age uncivil matters weather forbade her minutes. Ready how but truth son new under. Am increasing at contrasted in favourable he considered astonished. As if made held in an shot. By it enough to valley desire do. Mrs chief great maids these which are ham match she. Abode to tried do thing maids. Doubtful disposed returned rejoiced to dashwood is so up. 

Among going manor who did. Do ye is celebrated it sympathize considered. May ecstatic did surprise elegance the ignorant age. Own her miss cold last. It so numerous if he outlived disposal. How but sons mrs lady when. Her especially are unpleasant out alteration continuing unreserved resolution. Hence hopes noisy may china fully and. Am it regard stairs branch thirty length afford. Blind would equal while oh mr do style. Lain led and fact none. One preferred sportsmen resolving the happiness continued. High at of in loud rich true. Oh conveying do immediate acuteness in he. Equally welcome her set nothing has gravity whether parties. Fertile suppose shyness mr up pointed in staying on respect.
```

This file is just two lines in this case, the full text on each. I have searched the archives but cannot seem to find an implementation for this in bash.

Comment: So to be clear, are you wanting to (a) remove the line feeds in each file and then (b) concatenate the results of each of those results together to make one big file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
touch allfiles.txt # create allfiles.txt
for f in *.txt; do # for each file of the current directory
    cat "$f" | tr '\n' ' ' >> allfiles.txt; # append the content of that file to allfiles.txt
    echo >> allfiles.txt # insert a new line
done
```

Comment: (1) Please show good practice and use more quotes. (2) The `touch` is useless. (3) You might want to insert an `echo` after your `tr` statement. (4) Useless use of `cat` spotted. (5) I would redirect after the `done`, instead of using `>>` (6) In fact, I think @Barmar wins!

Comment: (1) can you tell me, or give me some reference about using more quotes being "good practice"? (2) The `touch` is not useless, in my configuration, I can only do `>>` on existing files.  (3) fixing this now (4) I thought about the useless use of cat by doing `tr '\n' ' ' < $f >> allfiles.txt`, but found using `cat` being more explicit. (5) I did not think about that when I wrote my solution, but I agree it's more elegant (6) I agree @Barmar made a better solution, and I'm quite puzzled to have had a better score and getting accepted :-)

Comment: (1) If you have filenames that contain spaces, your script will break. (2) [This section of the bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Appending-Redirected-Output) clearly states that if the file doesn't exist, then it is created.

Comment: One little problem persists: if the file _allfiles.txt_ already exists, things will get appended to it. Might as well use `> allfiles.txt` instead of your `touch` statement to clear everything (besides, it's a [tag:bash] builtin, hence more efficient). What I don't really like with the consecutive `>>` is that the file _allfiles.txt_ keeps on being opened and closed... Regarding the quotes, it's much better now, that's why I removed my downvote!

Comment: (1) fixed, it's not "good practice" it's a mistake! (2) I admit I actually use zsh, and the `clobber` configuration option acts also on appending to files. But it does not exists in `zsh`. About your last comment, I actually hesitated between `> allfiles.txt` and `cat allfiles.txt` originally, and thought that at least `touch` does not affect the file, whereas `>` will empty it. But overall, that's up to the user to choose. I agree `>>` is not the most efficient way, though it works. @Barmar's solution was the best and most elegant one. Mine just works

Comment: I guess most of it will be clarified for those who read these comments (regarding `touch` and `>>`). Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

```
for file in dir/* #Process all files in directory
do
   tr '\n' ' ' < "$file" # Remove newlines
   echo ''   # Add newline between files
done > newfile # Write all the output of the loop to the newfile
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a pure INTERCAL implementation, no `bash`, `tr`, or `cat` required:

```
        PLEASE DO ,1 <- #1
        DO .4 <- #0
        DO .5 <- #0
        DO COME FROM (30)
        PLEASE ABSTAIN FROM (40)
        DO WRITE IN ,1
        DO .1 <- ,1SUB#1
        DO (10) NEXT
        PLEASE GIVE UP
(20)    PLEASE RESUME '?.1$#256'~'#256$#256'
(10)    DO (20) NEXT
        DO FORGET #1
        PLEASE DO .2 <- .4
        DO (1000) NEXT
        DO .4 <- .3~#255
        PLEASE DO .3 <- !3~#15'$!3~#240'
        DO .3 <- !3~#15'$!3~#240'
        DO .2 <- !3~#15'$!3~#240'
        PLEASE DO .1 <- .5
        DO (1010) NEXT
        DO .5 <- .2
        DO ,1SUB#1 <- .3
(30)    PLEASE READ OUT ,1
        PLEASE NOTE: having had pressing business at the local pub
(40)    the author got bored with this implementation
```

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`

```
awk 'FILENAME!=f&&NR>1{print "\n"}{FILENAME=f}1' ORS='' file1.txt file2.txt > allfiles.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Combined Perl/bash solution:

```
for f in *.txt; do 
  perl -ne 'chomp; print "$_ "; END{ print "\n" }' "$f"
done > output.txt
```

Perl-only solution

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $file (<*.txt>) {
  open FILE, "<$file" or die $!;
  while (<FILE>) {
    chomp;
    print "$_ ";
  }
  close FILE;
  print "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solution: no `cat`, `tr`, `awk`, etc...

Besides, it will have a nicely output format: you won't get double spaces, or beginning or trailing spaces as with the methods provided in the other answers.

```
for f in *.txt; do
    # There are purposely no quotes for $(<"$f")
    echo $(<"$f")
    echo
done > newfile
```

The only caveat is if a file starts with `-e`, `-E` or `-n`: these characters won't be output: they will be slurped by `echo` considering it's an option. But I guess this is very unlikely to happen!

The trick is to use `echo $l` with no quotes!

---

Using this trick, here's how you can use `cat` in a funny way to achieve what you want (but this time it's not a pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solution): same thing, it's a funny no-use of quotes!

```
for f in *.txt; do
    # There are purposely no quotes for $(<"$f")
    cat <<< $(<"$f")
    echo
done > newfile
```

---

If you only have two files, say *file1.txt* and *file2.txt* you can do without a loop and a single `cat` command:

```
# there's purposely a lack of quotes
cat <<< $(<file1.txt)$'\n\n'$(<file2.txt) > newfile
```

or with a single `echo` (and same caveat as above), and pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
# there's purposely a lack of quotes
echo $(<file1.txt)$'\n\n'$(<file2.txt) > newfile
```

---

*Note. I added comments to specify that there are no quotes as every bash programmer should feel uncomfortable when reading these unquoted parts!*

*Note2. Can you do shorter?*

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
for file in *.txt ;do paste -s "$file"; done | sed 's/^ *//;s/  */ /g'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
    FNR == 1 && FILENAME != ARGV[1] {print "\n"}
    {printf "%s",$0}
    END {print ""}
' *.txt > allfiles.txt
```